# xrdp authentication using active directory in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote-desktop, active-directory

I used this tutorial to install xrdp on my ubuntu with active directory users: http://eurekamoment.eu/?p=999

Is there a way to specify which user groups from the active directory can connect to the computer using remote desktop? (Because it seems that it will allow every domain user to log in remotely.)

Or is there any other program that allows me to do it?

Comment: did you ever find an answer?